# Individual origins are not individual

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm in the UV image editor and I selected "individual origins" as the pivot. On my UV unwrap I selected very clearly, 100% bet my life on it, separate edges of the unwrap. Now, in regular edit mode, there is no problem with this, transform scale and rotate would all work by applying these transforms to those edges separately.

For seemingly no reason in the UV editor though, it keeps assuming the average as the pivot, even though it's set to individual origins. So when I scale these individual edges, instead of scaling them individually, it makes them shrink towards their center of their distance.

How can someone get the individual origins to work as it should?

Answer (score 3):

Is there any way you can post some images that display the problem? I can't duplicate it.

**Scale** with **Median** selected:

[image]

And then with **Individual Origins** selected:

[image]

**Rotate** with **Median**:

[image]

And **Individual Origins**:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea.